# Dialog crashes when setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-dialog

i create a custom dialog class This dialog works well and is displayed but when setOnClickListener app is crashes.I think the problem is in the setView, please guide.i call this class in the fragment/what's problem

```
clDialogs = new Cl_Dialogs();
clDialogs.showPopup(getContext());


package ir.lilola.org;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Cl_Dialogs {
Dialog dialog;
public void showPopup(Context context){
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Button Category = dialog.findViewById(R.id.category);
    final Button Date = dialog.findViewById(R.id.date);
    Button Time = dialog.findViewById(R.id.time);
    Button Confirm = dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    Confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    Button Delete = dialog.findViewById(R.id.del);
    EditText Price = dialog.findViewById(R.id.price);
    EditText Label = dialog.findViewById(R.id.label);
    TextView dateText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
    TextView timeText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    TextView labelText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.labelText);
    TextView priceText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_registers);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();

}
}
```

Comment: Please add crash logs

Comment: I can not use the simulator. I use the virtual device.Because of Iranian and American problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
dialog.setContentView(...);
```

earlier than any of the

```
dialog.findViewById(...);
```

This is because without contentView set up, `findViewById(..)` will return `null` because it could not find the view by given id.

Therefore, when you try to call `setOnClickListener(..)`, you are calling the method against `null`, end up getting `NullPointerException`

Take a look at the official document: [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setContentView(int))

Comment: TL;DR: put your `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_registers);` right below `dialog = new Dialog(context);`